# How do I call a URL that has a text file, convert it to a string and display it in ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

All I want to do is call a URL that has  text format data, convert it to a string variable and output it as a message or a toast in my ionc 2 app.
So far my app shows the button, but when I click it to activate the setMessage() function it doesn't show anything at all.

My code so far looks like this.

This is my about.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar primary>
    <ion-title>
      Sismos 
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding class="about">
<button (click)="setMessage()"> Button</button>

</ion-content>
```

This is my about.ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


//La libreria de abajo la importé para conectarme al Catalogo de Sismos
// el link es http://www.prsn.uprm.edu/Data/prsn/EarlyWarning/Catalogue.txt
//import {Http} from '@angular/http';



@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/about/about.html'
})
export class AboutPage {

                           message: any;
                           // items: any;
                                                        constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private http: Http)
                            {       
                              //  this.items = [];
                             }

     setMessage() {
                                                   let URL_Data = this.http.get('http://www.prsn.uprm.edu/Data/prsn/EarlyWarning/Catalogue.txt');
                                let message = URL_Data.toString();
                                                   return message;
                                           }               

                        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning a string but not doing anything with it. And you're setting the `message` but not showing it on your page.

Try  setting a variable in your html f.e. `<p>{{message}}</p>` (if using this don't forget to initialize your message, `message:string = "no message available";`)

In your .ts file

```
...//imports, component decorator

export class AboutPage{
  message:string = "no message yet";

  ..... //constructor etc.

  setMessage(){
    this.http.get("url").subscribe(response => {

        this.message = response.toString();

        //asynchronous method converting the returned Observable
        //(http.get returns Observable) and setting it to the message property.
    });
    //note that, code here will be executed BEFORE the subscribe method (asynchronous)
    //so make sure everything you need to do with the message or response is in the subscribe()
  }


}
```

Comment: I added the <p>{{message}}</p> in the html, but the string won't change values. Can you give me a full code example?

Comment: ah I see, no need for an entire example, just remove the `let` before message in your `setMessage()`

Comment: replace it with `this.message = URL_Data.toString();`

Comment: It's finally responding, but when I click the button it outputs [object Object] any idea on how to fix that. By the way thank you very much I'm finally making progress.

Comment: one moment, I'll try to recreate it

Comment: alright I can't recreate it since I'm using port 3000 and can't change atm (note that maybe nothing will change, if then, check your console (Ctrl+shift+i) -- if it complains about `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` then the API is not allowing your port/origin. Anyways, edited my answer with a solution